# TSQL invalid where clause in sub query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a situation where I need select the current and previous order amount in a single row using a select statement.

Order Table:

```
Customer Id
OrderId
OrderDate
OrderAmount
```

Current Select Statement:

```
SELECT o.OrderId, o.OrderDate, o.OrderAmount, po.OrderAmount
FROM Order o
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT TOP(1) so.OrderAmount
   FROM Order so
   WHERE so.CustomerId = o.CustomerId and so.OrderId <> o.OrderId
   ORDER BY so.OrderDate DESC
   ) po
```

The problem is that the "where" clause in the sub query is not allowed. Is there another method for getting this information.

This is actually a simplification of a more complex select (for a view) that requires data for financial reports for the current and previous reporting period.

Comment: By current do you mean the most recent order? So are you just looking to get the top 2 orders ordered by so.orderDae desc?

Comment: How is "previous row" determined? Is `ORDER BY OrderDate` unambiguous (no ties) or should it be  `ORDER BY OrderDate, OrderId`  to provide a tie breaker in the event of multiple rows with the same `OrderDate` value?

Comment: @Martin - You can assume that there is only one order per date for a customer. I have updated my original question to clarify my issue.

Comment: @Barry - I am trying to get the current and previous order amounts in a single row.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would need `OUTER APPLY` here.

Your `WHERE` clause doesn't look right though. I've assume `OrderDate` is unique below in being able to determine "previous" row.

```
SELECT o.OrderId,
       o.OrderDate,
       o.OrderAmount,
       po.OrderAmount
FROM   [Order] o
       OUTER APPLY(SELECT TOP(1) so.OrderAmount
                   FROM   [Order] so
                   WHERE  so.CustomerId = o.CustomerId
                          AND so.OrderDate < o.OrderDate
                   ORDER  BY so.OrderDate DESC) po
```

But you may well be better off left joining on `ROW_NUMBER`

```
;WITH Ord
     AS (SELECT OrderId,
                OrderDate,
                OrderAmount,
                CustomerId,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY CustomerId 
                                       ORDER BY OrderDate)  AS RN
         FROM   [Order])
SELECT o.OrderId,
       o.OrderDate,
       o.OrderAmount,
       po.OrderAmount
FROM   Ord o
       LEFT JOIN Ord po
         ON o.CustomerId = po.CustomerId
            AND o.RN = po.RN + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

enter code hereYour WHERE clause is not valid because the sub select has no context for the o alias.

Did you mean:

```
ON so.OrderId <> o.OrderId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT o.OrderId, o.OrderDate, o.OrderAmount, po.OrderAmount
FROM Order o
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT TOP(1) so.OrderAmount
   FROM Order so
   ORDER BY so.OrderDate DESC
   ) po on po.OrderId <> o.OrderId
```

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate the ROW_NUMBER idea

```
with TheOrders as
( 
    select  row_number() over(order by orderdate desc) as RowNum,
            o.OrderId as OrderId
    from Orders o
)
select * from TheOrders
```